# AttributeError: module 'jinja2.ext' has no attribute 'with_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jinja2, google-colaboratory, eli5

I tried to install eli5 Python package via the below command in my google colab file.

```
!pip install eli5
```

And I'm getting this error when running the above command.

> AttributeError: module 'jinja2.ext' has no attribute 'with_'

I tried to update jinja2 via the below commands, but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
!pip install --upgrade aiohttp_jinja2

!pip install --upgrade jinja2>=3.0
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

This problem is caused by incorrect versioning of the jinja2 package inside the eli5 itself. There are some PRs that address this issue.

So you can:

- wait for those PRs to be released in the new eli5 version

or

- quickfix it by installing jinja2 of version 3.0.0 - 3.0.2

`!pip install --upgrade jinja2>=3.0` didn't work because, I suppose, pip installed version greater than 3.0.2

Comment: Please also note; python version make sure 3.9 , it is not working with 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem, I debugged the issue with Pycharm.
I search for the tag `jinja2.ext` and found one package using this. To resolve that issue, I updated the package to the latest version.

In my case, I updated the package Flask-DebugToolbar 0.11.0 to 0.13.1. It resolves my issue.